# How do I specify input from a user?

Tags: java, input

I'm writing a program and I would like to call for a specially-formed string that consists of 3 letters (can be upper-case or lower-case), followed by a dash and then followed by 4 numbers.

For example, "abc-1234".

The value must follow this pattern, otherwise, they are invalid.

Comment: `if (string.matches("[a-zA-Z]{3}-[\\d]{4}")) { System.out.println("String is VALID!"); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String regex with `String`'s `match` method:

```
String pattern = "[\\w^\\d]{3}-\\d{4}";
```

This is a template for 'ccc-dddd', where d is a number from [0-9] and c is a word character, not including [0-9].

Then, you can see if your input string matches the template:

```
if(input.matches(pattern)) { //input is input string
   ...
} else {
   System.out.println("Input does not match template ccc-dddd");
}
```